# ImportError on urls.py while running the python Django app

Tags: python, django

I'm doing a Python-Django web app.And I got an error on urls.py when
I'm trying to run the project using `python manage.py runserver`
The below given is my error.

```
Not Found: /hello
    [09/Nov/2016 16:22:34] "GET /hello HTTP/1.1" 404 1920
    Performing system checks...

Unhandled exception in thread started by <function wrapper at 0xb68f7924>
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/nishanth/nenv/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/Django-1.10.3-py2.7.egg/django/utils/autoreload.py", line 226, in wrapper
    fn(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/home/nishanth/nenv/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/Django-1.10.3-py2.7.egg/django/core/management/commands/runserver.py", line 121, in inner_run
    self.check(display_num_errors=True)
  File "/home/nishanth/nenv/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/Django-1.10.3-py2.7.egg/django/core/management/base.py", line 374, in check
    include_deployment_checks=include_deployment_checks,
  File "/home/nishanth/nenv/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/Django-1.10.3-py2.7.egg/django/core/management/base.py", line 361, in _run_checks
    return checks.run_checks(**kwargs)
  File "/home/nishanth/nenv/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/Django-1.10.3-py2.7.egg/django/core/checks/registry.py", line 81, in run_checks
    new_errors = check(app_configs=app_configs)
  File "/home/nishanth/nenv/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/Django-1.10.3-py2.7.egg/django/core/checks/urls.py", line 14, in check_url_config
    return check_resolver(resolver)
  File "/home/nishanth/nenv/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/Django-1.10.3-py2.7.egg/django/core/checks/urls.py", line 24, in check_resolver
    for pattern in resolver.url_patterns:
  File "/home/nishanth/nenv/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/Django-1.10.3-py2.7.egg/django/utils/functional.py", line 35, in __get__
    res = instance.__dict__[self.name] = self.func(instance)
  File "/home/nishanth/nenv/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/Django-1.10.3-py2.7.egg/django/urls/resolvers.py", line 313, in url_patterns
    patterns = getattr(self.urlconf_module, "urlpatterns", self.urlconf_module)
  File "/home/nishanth/nenv/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/Django-1.10.3-py2.7.egg/django/utils/functional.py", line 35, in __get__
    res = instance.__dict__[self.name] = self.func(instance)
  File "/home/nishanth/nenv/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/Django-1.10.3-py2.7.egg/django/urls/resolvers.py", line 306, in urlconf_module
    return import_module(self.urlconf_name)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/importlib/__init__.py", line 37, in import_module
    __import__(name)
  File "/home/nishanth/Documents/register/register/urls.py", line 16, in <module>
    from django.conf.urls import patterns, include, url
ImportError: cannot import name patterns
Performing system checks...
```

This is my urls.py

```
from django.conf.urls import patterns, include, url
from django.contrib import admin

urlpatterns = patterns['',
    url(r'^admin/', admin.site.urls),
    url(r'^hello/$', 'blog.views.hello'),
    url(r'^hello_template/$' , 'blog.views.hello_template'),
]
```

How can I solve this problem

Comment: If this code comes from a tutorial, then it is out of date. The code above was written for Django 1.7 or earlier. If you are starting off learning Django, then please look for a more up-to-date tutorial, otherwise you'll have more problems like this.

Answer (score 5):

Newer versions of Django (like 1.10 which you're on) do not use `patterns`. Just put the urls in a list. You'll also need to import the view functions that will handle each url and supply those instead of the strings as parameters:

```
from django.conf.urls import url
from . import views

urlpatterns = [
    url(r'^admin/', admin.site.urls),
    url(r'^hello/$', views.hello),
    url(r'^hello_template/$' , views.hello_template),
]
```

See the https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.10/topics/http/urls/#example

Comment: @Alasdair I posted the example with the hope they'll pick up from there. Thanks for noting.